# Conditional format to color cell if matched from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight any cell in Columns B:H that match to Column A. Example:

[image: screenshot]

** I did try adding rules to the conditional format to use `=COUNTIF(B:F,A:A)>1` but no luck.

Comment: Hello, your column delimiters are not clear. Please clarify the formatting in this question by using the `Code` formatting feature and taking advantage of the monospaced font to separate columns.

Comment: You should probably start with Google to read documentation about conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks all for the constructive feedback! I wouldn't be asking here if got an answer from Google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with the formula you provided.

First, make sure that you **highlight** your entire B:H columns, then click conditional formatting.

You will use this custom rule:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,B1)>0
```

Comment: was just leaving this in the comments.